# POST в php и обновление контента

Tags: php, post

Есть два файла первый test.php содержит код содержание страницы

```
<script>
function getposition(){
    document.getElementById('msg').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('dannye').style.display='none';
    var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
    $.ajax({
        timeout: 960000,
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkposition.php",
        data: {keyword:keyword},
        success:function(search) {
            $('#instatable').html(data);
            document.getElementById('msg').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('dannye').style.display='block';
        }
    });
}
</script>
  <body style="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 id="navbar1">Позиция группы в поиске ВК</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="border-bottom border-primary">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="keyword">Запрос</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" value="saq">
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">ключевое слово или фраза</small>
                </div>
                
                <p align="right"><button class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="getposition()">Проверить позицию</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="msg" style="display:none">
            <center>
                <img src="https://grolik.ru/images/waiting.gif">
            </center>
        </div>
                
        <?php include ('checkposition.php');?>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

При нажатие на кнопку выполняется функция onclick="getposition()"
Файл checkposition.php содержит api запрос и генерацию таблицы с результатом

```
<?php
          $search_get = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.search?q=$_POST["keyword"]&access_token=токен&sort=1&v=5.131&count=50');
          $search = json_decode($search_get, true);
          $counter = 1
?>
        
       <div id="dannye" class="col-lg-14" style="display: block;">
        <legend id="inform"></legend>
        <table id="tblExport" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>№</th>
                    <th>Аватар</th>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>Короткая ссылка</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($search['response']['items'] as $item) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo '<td><img class="photo_group_200" src="'.$item['photo_50'].'"></td>';
    echo "<td>{$item['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$item['screen_name']}</td>";
    
    echo '</tr>';
}

 
                    ?>

                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Как сделать что бы после нажатия функция с пост запросом обработалась и отобразила таблицу в test.php

Comment: ответ получаете в search, а вставляете data... посмотрите для начала, что именно приходит в ответ на запрос